# how to add dictionary and get values

Tags: swift

sorry, I'm trying to add a json of type dictionary and get the values. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly, that's how it works for me, but when I get the values ​​of the function that the dictionary returns, my application doesn't get anything.
I tried to obtain this data in different ways. I don't know if someone could give me any idea, thank you.

```
 let jsonLifevitPBM_200 =  """


            {
            
            "result" : [
          
            {
           
            "id_d" : 55,
            "id_c" : "0",
            "data" : [
                    {
                    "Diastolic" : 85,
                    "ErrorCode" : -1,
                    "Systolic" : 120,
                    "Pulse" : 72
                    }
             ],
            "date_s" : "2021-07-28 09:45:16.201"
            
            }
            
            ],
             "error" : 0,
            "flags" : 0
        }

        """
     


        let jsonKelvin = Data(jsonLifevitPBM_200.utf8)
        
        let jsonKelvinResult = try? JSONDecoder().decode(VitalSignTermometreResponse.self, from: jsonKelvin)
        
        let temperature = jsonKelvinResult?.result[0].data[0].Temperature
        let mode = jsonKelvinResult?.result[0].data[0].Mode
        let unit = jsonKelvinResult?.result[0].data[0].Unit
        
        if let tem = temperature , let mod = mode , let uni = unit {
            labelsystole.text =  "Error: \(tem)"
            labeldiastole.text =  "Error: \(mod)"
            labelPulse.text =  "Error: \(uni)"
        } else {
            labelResult.text = "Error Medisana BU 575 Connect"
        }
```

Another way of trying to create the dictionary and get the data was this way, but I don't think it is in the correct way

```
let responseDevice : [String : Any] = [
                     "result" : [
                        "id_d" : 55,
                        "id_c" : "0",
                        "data" : [
                            "Diastolic" : 85,
                            "ErrorCode" : -1,
                            "Systolic" : 120,
                            "Pulse" : 72
                            ],
                        "date_s" : "2021-07-28 09:45:16.201"
                         ]
                     
                 ]


if  let dat = responseDevice["result"] as?  [String : Any] {
    if let resultData = dat["data"]   as?  [String : Any] {
            if let diast =  resultData["Diastolic"] as? String , 
            let systolic =  resultData["Systolic"] as? String {

                    println("Result : \(diast) - \(systolic)")
            }
    }
       
    }
```

Comment: Without the code for VitalSignTermometreResponse we don't really know what you are trying to do.

Comment: create a static dictionary and get the values ​​from that dictionary

Comment: You are posting the same question again and again but it is very hard to understand what you want to do and why you need this static dictionary. If it is really a Dictionary you want , what is wrong with your second attempt?

Comment: There is a function that returns the dictionary to me but I do not have access to that service, I can only simulate it with a static dictionary. when sending for revision they tell me that they do not get the data

Comment: Ok so this is for testing and that service returns a swift Dictionary or maybe it returns a json message which would make more sense? And again, what is wrong with your second attempt?

Comment: I try to form a dictionary based on the first example, I do not know if it is well formed or should I add braces '{..}' in the second example and the way to obtain the data from the array, first to know if the dictionary is well formed

Comment: A dictionary is a built in type, if it isn’t well formed then you will get a compilation error. But I honestly doubt that you talk about a dictionary, the mention of braces makes me believe you mean a json message. Who knows…

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that is to use a third party library to get JSON and after that you can manage JSON values.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Not only is the built in support for json much better than 3rd party libraries but the choice of how to decode json isn’t relevant here it seems